# Changing the angle of the vertical and horizontal axis of Sine curve

Tags: geometry, graphing-functions

> Suppose we have $f(x)=\sin{(x)}$

The plot of $f(x)$ :

[image: sin x]

---

**Suppose I want to modify the graph by :**

1. Changing the *angle of horizontal axis*: (Plane rotation...so both horizontal and the vertical axis changes)

[image: tilt]

> How to achieve this? I mean the whole graph will look **tilted** say at an angle $\theta$...

2. Changing the *angle of vertical axis*: (I guess it is called vertical axis!)

[image: italicized]

> Again, how to achieve this? I mean the whole graph will kind of look **italicized** at an angle $\phi$...[Keeping the horizontal axis same]

---

> **Hence, my question is how to achieve this rotation and tilt of $\sin(x)$**.By 'achieve' I mean the new equations. I guess there will be a **general** formula too for almost all *$f(x)$*.

**EDIT**

Also what will happen to the 1st question if the $z$-axis is involved (*Revolution of that graph*). That is how can i also revolve the curve along z axis?

BTW please give the new "equations" too along with "how-to-do" coz some examples help also along with the hints

**P.S.** - I know that after these transformations the curve may not remain a function but i still want the equations please!

***Thanks***

Comment: Not sure I understand what you're asking. For starters: If your transformation in 1 rotates the plane, the vertical axis also gets rotated, so your two questions seem identical. Do you want to "rotate" the horizontal axis while preserving the vertical axis in some way? (If so, maybe you're looking for the result of a "shear" transformation?)

Comment: In the 2nd case i mentioned that the horizontal axis remain fixed...But in the 1st question i did not mention anything...so anything can happen! I am aware that while rotating the horz. axis the ver axis will change...actually thats what i want in the 1st case...Full plane rotation!

Comment: Do you want to rotate entire graph $ y= \sin x  $ by some angle around  y- axis?

Comment: @Narasimham If you are talking about Q1, then yeah...suppose we change the horz axis to $y=2x$ from $y=0$...So angle becomes $\arctan{2}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only addressing Q#2, *italicizing*:

---

[image: SlantSin30]

---

The result above was achieved by multiplying by the 
[*shear matrix*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix#Shearing)
below, with $\phi=30^\circ$:
$$
M = \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & \tan (\phi )  \\
 0 & 1  \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
For $\phi=60^\circ$:

---

[image: SlantSin60]

---

If you parametrize the sine-curve as $(t, \sin (t))$, then multiplying by
the shear matrix results in
$$
M \cdot (\; t,\; \sin (t) \;) = \left( \; t + \sin (t) \tan (\phi ), \; \sin(t) \; \right) \;.
$$

---

This figure from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix) (employing homogenous coordinates, and so $3 \times 3$ matrices) may help.
I used the "Shear in the $x$-direction" matrix:

---

[image: Wikipedia]

Comment: Thanks for this answer...but would you mind me telling where did you plot this graph?

Comment: @NeilRoy: I used Mathematica.

Answer (score 1):

There is a method to rotate a graph, that is, using the general *rotation matrix*, however, there is no general method, lets say $M$, such that $M(f(x))=f(x)_\phi$, since a counterexample holds, assuming $f(x)$ is not monotonic on interval $[a,b]$:

Say that $f(x_1)=f(x_2) = y_1$ when $x_1 < x_2$, a tilt of 90° will guarantee that $f(y_1)_\phi = x_1 = x_2$, so $f_\phi$ is not a function.

Comment: Can you please go into a little bit more detail?

Comment: I'm assuming you want to rotate the function, not the plot of a function freely, so that the function rotated by method $M$ is not equal to the original function. If you just want to rotate the plot of a function, the general rotation matrix will do the trick: [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix)